# Firebase Auth, kicks user after change email

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase-authentication

I'm having a issue using Admin Firebase Sdk, when I change the email in my backend using the Firebase Sdk the current user is logged out.
This is my code in my backend:

```
const updateUser = (request, response) => { //Aggiorna le info dell'utente, nome e biografia, l'email verrà gestita da firebase
  const idToken = request.params.idToken
  const {
    fullname,
    bio,
    email
  } = request.body
  utils.firebase.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken) //verifico che il token sia vero
    .then(function(decodedToken) {
      let uid = decodedToken.uid //estrapolo lo uid dell'utente

      //modifico l'email su firebase
      utils.firebase.auth().updateUser(uid, {
          email: email,
        })
        .then(function(userRecord) {
          console.log("Firebase: Account aggiornato" + userRecord.toJSON())
          //Ora faccio l'update sul mio database
          utils.pool.query(
            'UPDATE users SET fullname = $1, bio = $2 WHERE uid = $3', [fullname, bio, uid], (error, results) => {
              if (error) {
                throw error
              }
              response.status(200).send(`Ares: User modified with ID: ${results}`)
            }
          )
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.log('Error updating user:', error);
          throw error
        });
    })
}
```

and this is my frontend (React):

```
const handleSubmitUpdate = (e) => {

  //Chiamo il mio backend, chiedendo di modificare le info dell'utente
  axios.put(`http://localhost:3001/users/` + context.currentUserToken, {
      fullname: user_name,
      bio: user_biography,
      email: user_email
    })
    .then(res => {
      console.log("User updated", res)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this happens is that Firebase uses JWT (PKI encrypted tokens) for authentication. Part of the JWT is the user's email address. If the email address changes, then the token the user has will can no longer authenticate because the email addresses won't match.

After changing email address you will need to log the user in again using an `auth().signInWith...` method. If the front end knows the email has changed it can be run proactively. Otherwise you can run it if you get a 401 response to an authenticated request.

Comment: Ok but for re-authenticate the user I need the password too, is secure to store the user password when he log in the first time and then use it to re-authenticate when he change the email??

Comment: It is probably not secure. The user will need to go through the login flow again after changing emails. i.e.... `auth().signInWithPopup(provider)` or equivalent... Basically do whatever you did the first time you logged the user in

Comment: Mmh but is so annoying for a user if he need to re-authenticate every time, there isnt another method to re-autenticate without ask the password and email again?

Comment: Everytime the user changes email address? Like I said.... Firebase auth uses JWT and the JWT access token include the email address. If the email address for a user changes then the JWT access token is no longer valid.